# How to set csv data files in slave & master machine for distributed testing?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, master-slave, distributed-testing

I have a created test plan in Jmeter . I did all the prerequisite configuration for master slave configuration in jmeter.properties file. I wanted to execute the plan with one master and two slave for 100 threads( using 50 threads for one slave).
I copied the test plan and csv in bin directory of master and slave machines in same location. Also I added the csv path in test plan in slave machines too.
I tried with multiple solution and go though the multiple solution on websites but still data is not getting fetch from csv from slave machine and load is not getting distributed on all slaves.

Could you suggest any solution for this?

I tried with multiple solution and go though the multiple solution on websites but still data is not getting fetch from csv from slave machine and load is not getting distributed on all slaves.

Could you suggest any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Any configuration should go into user.properties file

   - [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
   - [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
2. You don't need to copy the test plan onto slave machines, you need to only run JMeter Server process on them using [jmeter-server.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter-server.bat) or [jmeter-server](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter-server) scripts depending on your operating system
3. Copy the CSV file to all slaves and make sure to use either full path or correct relative path. The CSV file doesn't have to be present in the master machine
4. Ensure that [JMeter's RMI ports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) are correctly set and open in firewalls
5. Assuming all above each JMeter slave should pick up its own version of the CSV file, if it doesn't - check out what's in [jmeter-server.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on each slave, the reason should be there.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer so quickly!
But I am using different user logins in all CSV files, using 1 to 10 users in one CSV file which is placed in slave 1 & using 11 to 12 users in the second CSV file which is placed in the second slave.

I added the "CSV data set config" in the test plan. So how to add the path of both the CSV files  in the test plan which is in master machine?

Comment: The files must have the same name and live under the same path